# How many people initially had apples?

Tags: estimation, sampling, nonparametric

**Story problem:**

Assume 10 apples are distributed across $X$ unknown people, where each person has at least one apple. For each apple a biased coin is flipped to see if that apple should be kept or discarded. If every apple belonging to a person is thrown out they are removed from the line. Six apples, belonging to four people were allowed to be sold. Knowing $T=10$ (initial total), $R=6$ (recorded), $A=4$ (allowed people) - is there a way to come up with an expected value of $X$?

$X$ is actually bounded by counting arguments:

- $\min(X)=A$  (Lower bound is number of people allowed in, you just took some of their apples away but they had some left over)
- $\max(X)=A+(T-R)$   (Worst case scenario is the $T-R$ apples thrown away belogned to $T-R$ individual people)

**Simulation**

We came to realize that different partitions of the integer 10 among different sets had higher probability of producing the results than others.

For small numbers, we constructed all integer partitions of $T$, and kept those that had between $A$ and $T-R+A$ sets. We then sampled according to how probable that partition could happen assuming uniform probability across all combinations. (i.e. if one partition was 4 have 1 and 3 have 2 that could happen 453,600 different ways, etc.)

Assume for one trial $X_i=7$, and a random partition of 10 apples among 7 people, with each person having at least one, could be 4 have 1 and 3 have 2.

$[a, b, c, d, e, e, f, f, g, g]$

(i.e. the 9th and 10th apple belongs to person $g$). To determine which apples to be kept, consistent with known recorded value of $R=6$ we did a random permutation of 1...10 and kept the first 6 indices. Assume two possible results could be

- $[-, b, -, d, e, e, -, -, g, g]$
- $[-, b, -, d, -, e, -, f, g, g]$

The first one has four remaining people, which is consistent with our observed $A=4$, and passes the Monte Carlo test, whereas the latter doesn't match our observed data.

In the simulation we did this until 100,000 successes occurred that matched all $(T,R,A)$ and kept track of which $X$ value was used.

- X=4:        5675
- X=5:       20875
- X=6:       28235
- X=7:       26600
- X=8:       18615

Which gave $E[X]=6.3160$ in this case.

**Problem**

The actual problem has significantly larger numbers, on the order of hundred of thousands, where actual enumerations of integer partitions is quite impracticable. Even for relatively small values the probability of having a success in the Monte Carlo is dramatically low.

I understand there is a lot of *a priori* distributions which could be given, and are actually unknown, so we are assuming the simplest case of uniformity across everything.

With large numbers a continuous approximation might be applicable, but we couldn't figure out how to figure out the probability of matching $A$.

Given just the three numbers $(T,R,A)$ (where we can assume they are large), is there an approximate answer to what the expected value would be had they been partitioned as of above and the Monte Carlo ran infinitely long? (assuming that is the best methodology in this case; if there's a better theoretical model absolutely all ears)

Comment: It took me a few reads to understand the apple scenario. You might want to introduce the "sold" and "in line" terminology up front, or restate it somehow. Also, combinatorial probability is my worst nightmare but I have a feeling there is a theoretical solution to this problem.